# Wordpress Plugin: How to get post tags on post_publish(draft-to-publish,etc) event?

Tags: wordpress, tags, multisite

I am unable to get post tags during post creation. 
The scheme:
I trigger the 'draft_to_publish' event via hook: `add_action('draft_to_publish','global_publish_event_handler');`
Everything is working, but if i try to get the tags of current post via code:

```
$post_tags = wp_get_post_terms($post_id,"post_tag",array("fields" => "names"));
```

It returns an empty array. And if I store the id of post (during creation) and then try to access its tags by stored id(for example 777 and this value is stored during previous post creation), then I am good to go with it.

```
$post_tags = wp_get_post_terms(777,"post_tag",array("fields" => "names"));
```

Is it possible to get post tags on post creation?

**UPD:** Same problem with any taxomony including categories, tags and etc.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that there are 2 `save_post` hooks called in Gutenberg Editor, 1 during actual post save and 1 during meta saving/taxonomy terms linking. In order to check for a needed save_post hook you need to check if nonce is set in $_REQUEST. So if you need to achieve exact thing I needed to you will have to do some checking on a 'valid' `save_post` hook first.